# Django + Heroku: Images Work Until Next Push

Tags: python, django, heroku, static, gunicorn

I have a basic learning blog app that I am running into an issue with: a "blog post" with an image uploaded via the app's admin form works fine, until I push another version via heroku.  Then where the image was displays the broken img icon, and the app cannot find the image even though the picture target when I look at the picture address is the same.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamentally important about something - hence why I can't seem to fix this by google.  Does anyone know why I'm tripping up here, and am I even approaching this right?

I'm using Django + Gunicorn + dj-static to serve the static files.

Here is the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/static/blog/images')
    section = models.ForeignKey('Section')
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    posted_by = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

the view:

```
def detail(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    picture = post.picture
    context = {'post': post, 'picture': picture}
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

snip containing the image html:

```
<hr>
   <img src="{{ picture.url }}">
<hr>
```

settings.py dealing with static files:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

BOOTSTRAP3 = {'include_jquery': True}

LOGIN_URL = '/users/login'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#Herokusettings
if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default' : dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    DEBUG = False

    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoprojectcom/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    # Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
    )
```

and wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling, MediaCling

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bss.settings")
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
application = Cling(MediaCling(get_wsgi_application()))

#application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Thank you for giving this a look, I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about how all this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default upload location on Heroku is into temporary storage. This is because you will get a different web worker each time you deploy.

You need to use S3 or another location to store your files. Luckily this is well documented for Paperclip on Heroku.

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate that!